# Customising a button without adding a border or other content

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a WPF button

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource BrandedButton}">Continue</Button>
```

It's currently styled as follows:

```
<Style x:Key="BrandedButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LowlightBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Open Sans Light"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="35"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="50,10"/>
</Style>
```

[image]

Now, I want to control the colour (and nothing else) for hover/press/etc, so I've added another setter

```
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource BrandedButtonTemplate}"/>
```

And that points at this ControlTemplate. I've only seen examples which change the structure of the button, eg by adding a border:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="BrandedButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0">
        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource HighlightBrush}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource HighlightBrush}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource HighlightBrush}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

But that kills the layout that was previously applied:

[image]

Conversely, if I only include the `ContentPresenter` and omit the wrapping `Border`, the button disappears entirely.

How can I change the hover and press colours without changing anything else? What's the smallest/lightest implementation for what should be a trivial task?

Comment: Have you tried to add `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}"` on your style declaration? You also should add `Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"` to `ContentPresenter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ControlTemplate ignores the Button's `Padding` property.

Add a TemplateBinding of the ContentPresenter's `Margin`:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="BrandedButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="0">
        <ContentPresenter
            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        ...
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: So I need to manually copy any and all possible properties that _might_ be set on the button and add them to as a templatebinding?

Comment: At least all those that should actually be used in the template.

Comment: It works but... That's ridiculous. I need to predict every possible attribute someone might possibly choose to use on my button and then make sure the template has a matching "Set same as template" attribute? I could spend months making a single control, and still not cover all the bases

Comment: It is perhaps not much more than those mentioned here, maybe only BorderBrush and BorderThickness. Foreground and all Font related properties are automatically inherited by child elements in the template.